# Local storage is not defined in angular 17

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

Recently I am migrate angular from 16 to 17 and start showing localStorage is not defined error. I saw some solutions to disable ssr from angular.json

From

```
"server": "src/main.server.ts",
"prerender": true,
"ssr": {
  "entry": "server.ts"
}
```

To

```
"server": "src/main.server.ts",
"prerender": false,
"ssr": false
```

and it worked but is want to know there is an other way to use local storage without disabling ssr.

Comment: you should inject localStorate by some token inside of where it is used. in client module you should provide the real localStorage, and in the server one - something that will work in your application. For example null, and change all the references to storage?.setItem....

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution would be to access `localStorage` through the `DOCUMENT` DI token.

Here is a standalone component that you can use to verify that it works for you. It worked in my local environment using SSR in development mode.

```js
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrl: './test.component.scss'
})
export class TestComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {
    const localStorage = document.defaultView?.localStorage;

    if (localStorage) {
      const counter = localStorage.getItem('counter');

      if (counter) {
        localStorage.setItem('counter', (parseInt(counter) + 1).toString());
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('counter', '1');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here are some links for more information:

- [Important Considerations when Using Angular Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/main/docs/gotchas.md)
- [Supply a custom provider with @Inject](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#supply-a-custom-provider-with-inject)

Comment: This solution solved the localStorage issue and also solved accessing the ```document```. With the constructor exactly as it is above, you can use ```this.document.body.classList``` (or any other API exposed from it). Great solution, @John.

Answer (score 3):

Angular 17 basically comes with Fundamental changes in the Framework's architecture. Since you enabled SSR in your project, and if you are trying to access Localstorage or Sessionstorage from Constructor or any possible Lifecycles which will trigger in SSR will throw the above error u were getting. So if you feel you want to use some storage mechanism in Component initialisation then please wrap the storage access or setting code in an if condition. Please refer the below code;

```
constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
  this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<UserInfo>(
    JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
  );
}
```

}

So if you see the above code snippet, I had wrapped the sessionStorage related code inside an if condition. isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId) this gonna check if the user is in Browser or not. You may can try the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

During Server-side Rendering (SSR): If your Angular application uses Angular Universal or any form of server-side rendering, localStorage will not be available because localStorage is a browser-specific feature. Code executed on the server does not have access to browser APIs

Solution:

```
 private isLocalStorageAvailable = typeof localStorage !== 'undefined';

 // check everywhere you use loaclStorage
 if (this.isLocalStorageAvailable) {//code here}
```