# Local storage in an Angular stand-alone component

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components

I am trying to access local storage in an Angular stand-alone component.

Like this:

```
  Addtodo(todo: Todo) {
    console.log('I am hit here for adding Todo');

    console.log('I have been in Git in the parent', todo);

    const result = this.todos?.push(todo);
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(this.todos))


    console.log('rebjhbhjewbjker', result);
  }
```

But I am getting an error:

> [vite] Internal server error: localStorage is not defined

I am trying to access local storage.

Comment: Accessing stuff like `localStorage` and even `document` just got a little more complicated in Angular 17. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77534244/local-storage-is-not-defined-in-angular-17

Answer (score 2):

`LocalStorage` does not exist on the server. Please wrap the code that is failing in an *if* condition which checks if the platform the code is running on is from the browser!

```
import { Component, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

...
isBrowser: boolean;
...

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
}

Addtodo(todo: Todo) {
    console.log('I am hit here for adding Todo');

    console.log('I have been in Git in the parent', todo);

    const result = this.todos?.push(todo);
    if(this.isBrowser) {
        localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(this.todos))
    }

    console.log('rebjhbhjewbjker', result);
}
```